# convert min to max (and vice versa) in optimization

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Consider the constrained problem
$$
\min_x\{ f(x) : x \in X\} \tag{P}
$$
for some feasible region $X$.
Is it true that (P) is equivalent to (Q) defined below:
$$
-\max_x\{ -f(x) : x \in X\} \tag{Q}
$$

Comment: Yes, it holds always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing $f$ has a minimum at $x_0$ , then
$$\left\{ \forall x\in X : f(x) \geq f(x_0) \right\}\iff \left\{\forall x\in X : -f(x) \leq -f(x_0)\right\},$$ so the minimum of f turned to a maximum of $-f$.